# Rodar testes unitários com dependencias que estão no grupo exclusions

Tags: java, maven, jboss, junit

Estou com um cenário em que preciso rodar um teste com JUnit em uma funcionalidade que possui uma dependência externa, porém para rodar essa funcionalidade no servidor de aplicação preciso colocar essa dependência externa no grupo de **exclusions** no meu `pom.xml`. Só que no teste eu não preciso/não tenho o contêiner do **JBoss EAP 5** iniciado, que já possui essa dependência. E neste momento o teste acusa que a dependência não está disponível.

Alguém conhece alguma alternativa para executar o teste unitário com a dependência externa, e na hora de empacotar o meu projeto em um jar/war realizar a exclusão devidamente.

Abaixo coloco a dependência em questão:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.21</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente adicionar explicitamente as duas dependências transitivas que você excluiu ao adicionar `nekohtml`, definindo escopo `test` para elas:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note a tag que adicionei, `<scope>test</scope>`. Isto fará com que esta dependência esteja disponível durante os testes e manterá a dependência fora do pacote de distribuição.

Caso estas dependências sejam necessárias também para o código de produção e não apenas para o código de testes, você pode usar o escopo *provided* (`<scope>provided</scope>`), assim as dependências serão utilizadas durante a compilação e durante os testes, mas não serão incluídas no pacote de distribuição.

Comment: Caso eu faça isso, o NekoHtml não vai estar disponível no meu pacote, e o única dependência que não preciso em runtime é a do xerces/xml-apis.

Comment: @eliocapelati Acho que entendi tua necessidade. Atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @Caffé, eu já tinha cogitado essa alternativa, pensei ter alguma coisa especifica para declarar as dependências seletivamente... De qualquer forma muito obrigado pela resposta! Acabei utilizando o scopo `provided` que se encaixou melhor conforme a documentação do maven: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-dependency-scope